# Basis of exterior product

Tags: multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ with basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$.

1. For a fixed tuple $I = (i_1,\ldots,i_r)$ with $1 \le i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \le n$, use multilinear extension to conclude that there exists a multilinear map $\varphi_I: V^r \rightarrow K$ such that

\begin{align}
\varphi_I(e_{j_1}, \ldots, e_{j_r}) &= \begin{cases} (-1)^{sgn(\sigma)} \quad \text{if there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $[r]$ with $\sigma(j_k) = i_k$ for all $k \in [r]$}\\ 0 \qquad  \text{else}\end{cases}
\end{align}

for all $(j_1,\ldots,j_r) \in [n]^r$.

1. Show that $\varphi_I$ is alternating and deduce by factorisation
   that there exists a linear map $f: \wedge^r V \rightarrow K$
   satisfying $f \circ \wedge^r = \varphi_I$.
2. Show that the set $A := \{e_{j_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge e_{j_r} : 1 \le j_1 < j_2 < \cdots < j_r \le n \}$ is linearly independent. Hint: Consider a linear relation of these elements and apply suitable maps
   $f$ to conclude all the coefficients are zero.

I got the first two points, but I do not understand how to use the hint for the third. Could you please help me?

Edit: Here is my attempt: We consider the sum
$$\sum_{a \in A}c_aa =0$$
,where the $c_a$ are scalars.Using the $f$ from above on the above equation yields

$$\sum_{a \in A} c_af(a) = 0.$$

However, when I use the definition of $f$ from above here I get

$$\sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal {S}_n} c_{\sigma}(-1)^\sigma = 0.$$

But this does not imply that all $c_\sigma$ are zero, since $\sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal {S}_n} (-1)^\sigma= 0$. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The usual method to prove linear independence is to suppose $c_1v_1+\dots+c_rv_r=0$ and show all the $c_i=0$. Do that here with your $e_J$ and show that $c_J=0$ by choosing a suitable $f_J$ from above.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Yes, you should have put this all there in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of $f$ the $r$-tuple $I$ is fixed. The particular $I$ appears exactly once in your set $A$. So you get $\pm c_I = 0$.